# How do I find the true list of IPO's and delistings on the NASDAQ?

Tags: nasdaq, delisting

How do I find out which companies are added and which ones are removed from the NASDAQ. I found lists on the internet, but they don't seem comprehensive or the source of the real data. For example, https://stockanalysis.com/actions/delisted/. Another example: when was DNKN (Dunkin Donuts) added then removed from NASDAQ?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google search of NASDAQ:

[Issues Pending Suspension or Delisting](https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/IssuersPendingSuspensionDelisting.aspx)

> Each trading day, Nasdaq publishes a list of Nasdaq issues that are pending suspension or delisting. An issue will appear on this list the first trading day after the issuer provides Nasdaq with notification of its intent to voluntarily delist. An issue will also appear on this list if it has been suspended for failure to meet continued listing requirements or due to other events such as expiration, redemption, or acquisition of the security.

[IPO Calendar](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/ipos)

Comment: that only shows pending delistings. how to find the start and end dates of something like DNKN? also, do I really have to scroll the list to find the exact stock, nothing shows it from the stock itself?